# Error cannot fin symbol en java

Tags: java, vscode

He estado buscando y viendo problemas iguales y sigue sin funcionarme. Importo todo y sigue saliendome el error de cannot find symbol. El paquete es una carpeta llamada proyecto y dentro de ella tengo 3 clases. La clase Jugador hereda de la Clase Persona pero no entiendo mi error. No se que me falta por importar y he buscado en este foro y en varios. Os dejo la imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado la clase persona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes  mostrar  la clase Persona? Pretendes  ejecutar Jugador.java?

Comment: Acabo de añadir la clase Persona

Comment: Tu problema es que estas utilizando Java Jugador.java y  es como si lo quisieras ejecutar y no compilar. Tienes que compilar Persona primero . Utiliza javac  para compilar

Comment: Mi proposito es que no tenga que compilar Persona primero, solamente quiero compilar Jugador.java y que no tenga que compilar a la vez Persona.java. Que tendria que hacer para ello?

Comment: Por lo que sé en Java se compilan todas las dependencias de la clase. Solo tienes que hacerlo una vez y luego el compilador va a encontrar  la clase.

Comment: El comando seria: java Persona.java Jugador.java ?? Y ya podria compilar solamente Jugador.java?

Comment: Utiliza: javac Persona.java Jugador.java

Comment: Se me han generado 2 archivos .class pero no se que realizar con ellos

Comment: ¿Estás aprendiendo Java? Los archivos  .class son los ejecutables para el Java.  Si al compilar se genera el archivo .class es que tu archivo .java no tienen error. Los .class son los archivos que se  cargan en la  vm del java para ejecutarse.

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo cuando escribes `javac *` o algo similar, si existe ya un archivo .class previamente compilado, no se compila nuevamente

Comment: La cosa es que no se como compilar solamente la clase Jugador ya que es en esa en la que me da error solo. PD: solo uso vs code y compilo siempre por terminal(si,odio eclipse y netbeans) y necesito saber como solucionar esto ya que soy principiante en java.

Comment: Agrega el código como imagen, algunos usuarios no pueden ver el código en imagen.

Comment: @tomas_hm01 aquellos que usan vscode con java normalmente tienen muchos problemas porque el complemento está muy limitado, te recomiendo cambiar de ide hasta que tengas un buen nivel de conocimiento para entender que podría estar mal configurado